# php mysql Get monthly sales group by timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this `order` table

```
| order_id | sales | order_date(timestamp) |
      2      100      2013-10-30 04:07:01
      3      300      2013-10-31 04:30:02
      4      400      2014-01-10 08:07:01
```

and here is my query, `$m1` and `$m2` are from `order_date`

```
SELECT `order_id`, MONTH(`order_date`) AS month, 
COUNT( `order_id`) AS orders_made,
SUM(`total`) AS sales, YEAR(`order_date`) AS YEAR
FROM  `orders` 
WHERE  `order_date` BETWEEN ('$m1') AND ('$m2') 
GROUP BY MONTH(`order_date`)
```

And this is what I got

```
| month | year | sales | orders_made |
    10    2013    100        1
    11    2014    400        1
```

My query does not return all the data that I wanted, what should be the query to display something like this

```
| month | year | sales | orders_made |
    10    2013    400        2
    11    2014    400        1
```

Need your help guys

Comment: Shouldn't your GROUP BY be `GROUP BY YEAR(order_date), MONTH(order_date)`?

Comment: How are you creating your $m1 and $m2 time stamps?

Comment: @Gavin it's from `order_date`

Comment: Ok, but how are you creating the timestamps in php?

Comment: $month1=$row['order_date'] then $m1=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($month1));

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT YEAR(order_date), 
       MONTH(order_date),
       COUNT(order_id) AS orders_made,
       SUM(sales) AS sales 
FROM orders 
WHERE order_date BETWEEN ('$m1') AND ('$m2') 
GROUP BY YEAR(order_date), MONTH(order_date)
```

Comment: thanks, but what if I compare different months but the same year ?? this is where I'm stuck

Comment: This will work for different months even if in the same year.

Comment: I now have 2 orders in October and 2 in November, I tried comparing orders from `October` to `november` in the same year but it doesn't return 1 order from november but works fine if I compare orders from different years